# How to serve images via serving url, that are uploaded to google cloud storage from google compute engine

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

In the past I had used Images API for that. But the blobstore and images APIs are available only within the App Engine runtime environment. Now I use google compute engine and I want to create serving url for the images uploaded to google cloud storage. How to do that? Is it possible images to be directly served from google cloud storage?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to use Custom images that you have stored in a Bucket in GCE in order to create VMs based on that custom (uploaded image). Is this correct?

Comment: Also, The python tag is because you are using a GCP library?

Comment: I want https://url_to_jpeg_from_gc_storage. I don't want to create VMs based on OS image. The python tag is because I use Google client python library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions, the first one could be use [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) which gives time-limited resource access to anyone in possession of the URL.

The second option is use [Request endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints) (example : https://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]). Something important to mention is that you need to grant the correct roles to the bucket in order to access it.

Comment: I will accept this answer, because it really is answer to the question that I asked, but it is not what I want. I need static like access to these files which is what I meant saying serving url. I already have implemented the second solution, and it works, but this is downloading the blob from the storage and then it returns it inside request. This is slowing down the request.

Comment: There really is solution to this that I found, but I cannot implement it because I don't have access to the CNAME settings of the domain. The solution is to set cloud storage to serve static site and to use this setting to serve static images.

Comment: But the answer leads to what you want. By using buckets you serve static files through CDN. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/serving-static-files